# How to remove insignificant whitespace in XML?

Tags: ballerina

Consider the following valid Ballerina program that prints twice an XML structure that has been created with [XML template](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/data/#xml-templates):

```
import ballerina/io;
public function main() {
    xml x = xml`<root >
        <foo>
            <bar>BAR</bar>
        </foo>
    </root >`;

    io:println(x);
    io:println(xml:strip(x));
}
```

The both print statements output the following identical string:

```xml
<root>
        <foo>
            <bar>BAR</bar>
        </foo>
    </root>
```

**First question:** how I can create the following output:

```xml
<root><foo><bar>BAR</bar></foo></root>
```

Without obfuscating the XML template:

```
// this method doesn't scale for real use cases
xml x = xml`<root ><foo><bar>BAR</bar></foo></root >`;
```

**Second question:** in this case [`xml:strip()`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.xml/latest/functions#strip) looks like no-op. Can it be used to solve the question #1? How to use it correctly? Based on the documentation:

> Strips the insignificant parts of the an xml value.
>
> Comment items, processing instruction items are considered
> insignificant. After removal of comments and processing instructions,
> the text is grouped into the biggest possible chunks (i.e., only
> elements cause division into multiple chunks) and a chunk is
> considered insignificant if the entire chunk is whitespace.

I was expecting to get:

```xml
<root><foo><bar>BAR</bar></foo></root>
```

But obviously I was wrong.

I'm using:

```
$ bal --version
Ballerina 2201.2.0 (Swan Lake Update 2)
Language specification 2022R3
Update Tool 1.3.10
```

Answer (score 3):

`xml:strip()` won't work here because you are trying to get rid of newline characters that are considered as `xml:Text` items in your current xml sequence. You could maybe try something like this:

```
import ballerina/regex;
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    xml testXML = xml `<root>
        <foo>
            <bar>BAR</bar>
        </foo>
    </root>`;

    string text = testXML.toString();
    string[] res = regex:split(text.trim(), "\\s+");
    string tempText = string:'join("", ...res);

    io:StringReader reader = new io:StringReader(tempText);
    xml|error? newXML = reader.readXml();

    io:println(newXML);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach fails with `<bar>BAR BAR</bar>` as it will also remove the whitespace in the text nodes (`<bar>BARBAR</bar>`). So this is applicable only in very limited scenarios at best. I'm not sure if it is possible to create a regular expression that would work correctly in all cases.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate a case where `xml:strip()` actually does something?

Comment: Ya you can change the regex to match your scenario. As for the next question, if you consider an `xml` sequence like: `Text<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?><root>Elem</root><!-- hello from comment -->` this contains `xml:Text`, `xml:ProcessingInstruction`, `xml:Element` and `xml:Comment` receptively. After you perform `xml:strip()` on this, the `xml:ProcessingInstruction` and `xml:Comment` items will be removed and you will be left with:  `Text<root>Elem</root>` which only contains `xml:Element` and `xml:Text` items.